# VBScript in Reports Expression Editor, filtering out certain values

Tags: vbscript, filter, report, expression, rdlc

I have a report that need null values replaced with N/A.  It works for x amount of rows until the null value is hit then the rest of the data needing to be displayed just goes away.

Here is my expression

```
=iif(Fields!PastBaseline.Value is nothing, "N/A", Round(Fields!PastBaseline.Value))
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used similar things many time and it works fine. Try it like this:

```
=iif( IsNothing( Fields!PastBaseline.Value ), "N/A", Round(Fields!PastBaseline.Value))
```

If this does not work can you see if there are any errors or warnings.

Comment: Tried this out, does the same thing as my code does, hit the first value and changes it to N/A then stops. I'll continue looking into it and let you know.

Comment: Can you try something else then replace "N/A" with 0.0(number) and see if it works. Also go to View->Output and in the output combo select "Debug" and see if the report viewer is writing some warnings or errors there

Comment: Figured it out!, your way works as well as mine.  The issue was after I have the expression evaluated it is trying to format it as a percent, which N/A can't be a percentage.  For some reason it doesn't want to give me an error message though.  Thanks